Convexity and a space of integrable functions
Let $\phi$ be a convex function from $\mathbf{R}_+$ to $\mathbf{R}$ that is null on $0$ and strictly positive on $\mathbf{R}^*_+$. We say that $V$ is the space of piecewise continuous functions from $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}$ such that $\phi \circ |f|$ is integrable on $\mathbf{R}$. Show that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbf{R}^\mathbf{R}$ if and only if $\alpha : x \in \mathbf{R}_+^* \mapsto \frac{\phi(2x)}{\phi(x)}$ is bounded.
I first solved the reciprocal : suppose that $\alpha$ is bounded. Using the hypotheses, it appears that $\phi$ must be strictly increasing. Therefore, $\phi \circ |f + g| \leq \phi \circ (|f| + |g|) = \phi \circ (\frac12 2|f| + \frac122|g|) \leq \frac12 \phi \circ (2|f|) + \frac12 \phi \circ (2|g|) \leq \frac C2 (\phi \circ |f| + \phi \circ |g|)$. Therefore, $f + g$ is in $V$. And with $\lambda \in \mathbf{R}$, one have $\phi \circ (|\lambda| |f|) \leq \phi \circ (2^k |f|) \leq C^k \cdot \phi \circ |f|$. Therefore, $\lambda \cdot f \in V$. And for the $0$, it is clearly in $V$ according to the hypotheses.
However, I can't find a solution for the other direction. I said that if we take $f = \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$, we must have $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \phi \circ (\lambda |f|) = \phi(\lambda)$. If $\frac{\phi(2x)}{\phi(x)}$ isn't bounded, then we will find a sequence $(x_n)$ such that from a certain rank, $\phi(2x_n) \gg \phi(x_n)$ and the integrability shouldn't be possible. Yet I don't know how to conclude.
Does anyone have any ideas on this one ?

Here, the integrable means the desired integral is finite I guess?

Yes, in this very particular case, we can just say that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi \circ |f| < +\infty$ (given that $\phi$ is positive).
